# Repeating Counts in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
      'item':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k'],
      'counter':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
      })
```

Given this structure, what is the best way to auto-generate `df['counter']` as a repeating range of integers, cycling through 1, 2, and 3 until it comes to the last row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df["counter_gen"] = df.index % 3 + 1
```

`+1` will get rid of the zero since mod starts from zero, and the `3` is determined by you.

Answer (score 2):

By using `np.put`

```
a=df.index.values
a
Out[637]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64)
np.put(a,a,np.array([1,2,3]))
a
Out[639]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
df['New']=a
df
Out[641]: 
   counter item  New
1        1    a    1
2        2    b    2
3        3    c    3
1        1    d    1
2        2    e    2
3        3    f    3
1        1    g    1
2        2    h    2
3        3    i    3
1        1    k    1
```

Comment: put's an inplace operation? If you don't make a copy of the index, does this also replace the index of the dataframe inplace as seen above?

Comment: @Jarad yep you are right , I even did not notice that , cool ~

Comment: Thanks for sharing put, I wasn't familiar! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Jarad nope , you are better than me , without your input I even did not notice that is inplace operation cheers

Answer (score 0):

If performance is crucial, you may be able to make use of something like

```
np.repeat([[1, 2, 3]], len(df)/3 + 1, 0).ravel()
```

For a length 10^6 data frame, this is roughly 8 times faster to generate than the (much more elegant) `df.index % 3`.